# "\pset numericlocale" is not picking the set lc_numeric in postgres

Tags: postgresql

the lc_numeric set by default is

```
postgres=# show lc_numeric;
         lc_numeric
----------------------------
 English_United States.1252
(1 row)
```

When we do \pset numericlocale. the output is coming as

```
postgres=# select 10000000.00;
   ?column?
---------------
 10,000,000.00
(1 row)
```

However if we manually change the lc_numeric to any other which should result is '.' as group separator and ',' as decimal separator. It is still returning as below,

```
postgres=# show lc_numeric;
 lc_numeric
------------
 de_DE
(1 row)


postgres=# \pset numericlocale
Locale-adjusted numeric output is on.
postgres=# select 10000000.00
postgres-# ;
   ?column?
---------------
 10,000,000.00
(1 row)
```

where as if I use to_char function the output is as below,

```
postgres=# select to_char(1000000.00,'999G999G999D99');
     to_char
-----------------
    1.000.000,00
(1 row)
```

We cannot use to_char function as there are many numeric columns which could be having any number of digits. So we want a common setting that would work for all numeric columns at once.

Why is the \pset numericlocale not picking the set lc_numeric to consider '.' as group separator and ',' as decimal separator??

Answer (score 1):

`\pset numericlocale` specifies how the *client* `psql` formats numbers as strings, while `lc_numeric` determines how the *server* does it.

So `lc_numeric` influences the result of

```
SELECT to_char(10000000, '999G999G999D99');

     to_char     
═════════════════
   10.000.000,00
(1 row)
```

(where the server does the conversion), while `numericlocale` influences the display of

```
SELECT 10000000;
```

Comment: Makes sense. Is there a way to make numericlocale to display the value same like using to_char with lc_numeric.?

Comment: No, you cannot specify a format. You get the numbers rendered in a way `psql` thinks fit for the (client) language. I have never used `numericlocale`, and it doesn't seem to be a very sophisticated tool.